# How to generate jhipster app with protractor tests

Tags: testing, protractor, jhipster

I have installed Jhipster 4.9.0, and when i run "jhipster" command to generate my app, i only have Cucumber and Gatling as testing options.

I would like to know how to generate my app with protractor tests.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Protractor test option only shows for `Gateway` and `Monolithic` app types, as a frontend is required for Protractor tests to run.

When using `jhipster client`, you can pass `--protractor` to enable Protractor tests.  To see other available options, run `jhipster client --help`

Comment: What about when i execute "jhipster client", it doesn't show there, it's confusing. At least to me.
Anyways, your answer has worked for me, thanks!

Comment: Run `jhipster client --help` to see all options.  For Protractor, add `--protractor`